# Lubridate in R throws up infinite recursion error; but only after 48K rows

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

My table "[march](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwrIp0071Y2tSmJWZzRZOWR5d0E/view?usp=sharing)" has 92,497 rows and two columns.

```
head(march)
   Unique.Key             ReportDate
1:   30062874 03/01/2015 12:08:00 AM
2:   30062909 03/01/2015 01:43:57 AM
3:   30062973 03/01/2015 01:36:21 AM
4:   30063031 03/01/2015 12:44:00 AM
5:   30063086 03/01/2015 01:22:59 AM
6:   30063107 03/01/2015 02:00:54 AM
```

I'm trying to convert the dates to POSIXct using `lubridate`. Starting with a smaller file of 500 rows, this:

```
march$ReportDate <- mdy_hms(march$ReportDate, tz="")
```

gave me:

```
   Unique.Key          ReportDate
1:   30180483 2015-03-15 23:59:00
2:   30181183 2015-03-15 23:58:00
3:   30185134 2015-03-15 23:56:24
```

Trying to run it on the full table with 92K rows, I got this error:

> Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
>
> Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?

Reducing number of rows, I was able to convert up to 48,000 rows. The error comes back at rows => 48,001. Line 48,001 itself looked fine. I skipped 47,999 rows in read.csv and the remaining 44K rows converted as expected.

The CSV is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwrIp0071Y2tSmJWZzRZOWR5d0E/view?usp=sharing).  I'm on a Mac 10.9 and using Rstudio v0.98,

```
sessionInfo() 
R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09) 
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit) 
Running under: OS X 10.9.1 

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8 

attached base packages:
[1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base 

other attached packages:
[1] lubridate_1.3.3 plyr_1.8.2 data.table_1.9.4 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] chron_2.3-45   digest_0.6.8     magrittr_1.5     memoise_0.2.1
[5] Rcpp_0.11.6    reshape2_1.4.1   stringi_0.4-1    stringr_1.0.0
[9] tools_3.1.3
```

Appreciate pointers/suggestions what's going on.

Comment: I haven't checked your file. Is your original date format same for all rows?

Comment: No problem for me to convert 92,497 dates with `mdy_hms`. What is your `sessionInfo()`? Knowing the version of RStudio is quite useless.

Comment: I also couldn't reproduce the problem in R 3.2.0 on linux mint 17.  Considering that you have a data.table, I used `setDT(march)[, ReportDate := mdy_hms(ReportDate, tz='')]`

Comment: @akrun: Thx, tried setDT as suggested but gives the same error as in my orig. post. Aslo tried in R 3.1.3 and same error.

User227710: Yes date format is the same for all rows. Datetimes convert without error if under 48K rows.

Comment: @manohar can you update to `R 3.2.0` .  I used the `data.table_1.9.5` i.e. the devel version.

Comment: @Pascal: Tried in R 3.13, got same error. sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.9.1

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] lubridate_1.3.3  plyr_1.8.2       data.table_1.9.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] chron_2.3-45   digest_0.6.8   magrittr_1.5   memoise_0.2.1 
[5] Rcpp_0.11.6    reshape2_1.4.1 stringi_0.4-1  stringr_1.0.0 
[9] tools_3.1.3

Comment: Have you tried it on R console?

Comment: @akrun Updated to R 3.2.0 and lubridate conversion still did not work. BUT as.POSIXct worked. Also worked on 500K rows, and then 2 million rows (the actual dataset). All in Rstudio. As Pascal suggested - maybe some weird interaction of lubridate package with something else.

Comment: I don't know what is going on.  I am using in R console and things are working.  Why don't you try R console for a change?

Comment: @akrun Sorry, yes I did. With data.table 1.9.4. Will try later on my Macbook (Yosemite and a lot cleaner) and see if the lubridate problem goes away.